# Scrapy: cannot change url of request object in process_request of DownloadMiddleware

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to build a download milddleware of scrapy which can change the url of request object. But I cannot get it work with process_request, as the download page is still the original url one. my code is as follows:

```
#middlewares.py
class UrlModifyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        original_url = request.url
        m_url = 'http://whatsmyuseragent.com/'
        request.url = m_url
        #request = request.replace(url=relay_url)
```

The code for spider:

```
#spider/test_spider.py
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http import Request

class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "urltest"
    start_url = "http://www.icanhazip.com/"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(self.start_url,callback=self.parse_start) 

    def parse_start(self,response):
        html_page = response.body
        open('test.html', 'wb').write(html_page)
```

In settings.py I set:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'official_index.middlewares.UrlModifyMiddleware': 100,
}
```

Comment: What scrapy version are you using? I did a test project with your exact code and worked as expected: the start request.url is whatsmyuseragent.com.

Comment: @Rho Thank you for answering. I am using 0.14.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test my exact code with scrapy 0.18.0. The code works fine. I guess maybe it's a bug of version 0.14.4.